# Java 8 Filtering Custom Class Properties

Tags: java, selenium, arraylist

I've been going through SO pages all morning trying to figure out the best way to attack my question:

What is the most efficient way to sort through an ArrayList, match on a name in the ArrayList with a name I'm pulling from a WebElement. I'm not experienced with Java, and wondering if this context it makes more sense to use HashTables, but I couldn't find an easily understandable answer on how to use them with multiple values per index:

My custom class:

```
public class KnowledgePermission {
    public String name;
    public String htmlType;
    public Boolean isAllowed;


    public KnowledgePermission(String name, String htmlType, Boolean isAllowed) {
        this.name = name;
        this.htmlType = htmlType;
        this.isAllowed = isAllowed;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getHtmlType() {
        return htmlType;
    }

    public Boolean getIsAllowed() {
        return isAllowed;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean result = false;
        if(obj instanceof KnowledgePermission) {
            KnowledgePermission otherPermission = (KnowledgePermission) obj;
            result = (this.name == otherPermission.name);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + htmlType.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + isAllowed.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm able to use Java 8, so I've looked at filters, haven't been successful yet.

Here's the snippet after I've created a list using my class type.

What I'm trying to do is get the XPath of some browser page items, get its name via Selenium's WebDriver API, and for the one item I know should match in my permission list, access one of the other two properties - htmlType or isAllowed - and continue logic based off of that.

```
List<KnowledgePermission> permissionList = new ArrayList<KnowledgePermission>();

permissionList.add(new KnowledgePermission("checkbox1sName", "checkbox", true ));
        permissionList.add(new KnowledgePermission("checkbox2sName", "checkbox", true ));

List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*someXpathinfoHere//input[@type='checkbox']"));

        // check the value of each checkbox and display
        for(WebElement item : checkboxes) {
            String elname = item.getAttribute("name");
            Boolean hasBeenSelected = item.isSelected();

            // find the permission in the list
            System.out.println("filtering permissions list");
            List<KnowledgePermission> currentPermission = permissionList.stream().filter(permission -> elname.equals(permission)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(currentPermission);
}
```

All that prints out for each iteration of the loop is:

```
filtering permissions list
[]
```

So I'm guessing I'm not understanding filtering correctly here.
Any help and I'd be grateful!!

Comment: If you want to have multiple values per key in a map then either use a multimap implementation (Google Guava has some) or use a collection type (list or set) as the value of the map. If performance is an issue don't create the map inside the method but build it beforehand and reuse it - unless it can change at each call.

Comment: Ok, thanks Thomas. I saw alot of suggetions about Guava, and seems to make sense. I come from a scripting background, so alot of those types of needs are already abstracted away in things like Python, PowerShell,etc. Appreciate it!

Comment: Note that `elname.equals(permission)` will always return false because `elname` is of type `String` while `permission` is of type `KnowledgePermission`. You probably want to use `elname.equals(permission.getName())` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
.filter(permission -> elname.equals(permission.getName()))
```

... is all you have to change

If elname can be null, change the order to

```
.filter(permission -> permission.getName().equals(elname))
```

Since instance.equals(null) returns false, not NullPointerException

Comment: Thanks Tomas, but what I need is access to mutiple keys based on a matching value instead of a boolean result. Thanks for the quick response though. Looks like Multimap it is

Comment: I ended up just using a regular HashMap and sending in name I had as a String key and the Values I wanted as non-spaced, comma separated strings. It felt hacky, but for now it works. Appreciate yours and Thomas' input. Learning Java as I go!